# Parts of Flot Chart Not Displayed

Tags: javascript, flot

I am developing a flot chart to include in an existing web site. When I create the chart in an otherwise empty web page, for development purposes, everything renders correctly.

But when I add it to the web site, parts of the chart to not display (this applies regardless of the chart type: line, bar or stacked). Here's what does not show:
(1) The chart title, which I have done as a top xaxis
(2) The xaxis ticks (except for part of the first one)
(3) The xaxis (bottom) label
(4) The yaxis label, although the yaxis ticks DO appear

Also, the yaxis ticks, while they appear, they are off by a half. So instead of 0 being at the lower corner, it is below the x axis, and the next y tick is positioned between 0 and its grid line, etc. So when a bar chart is rendered that has a value of 500, it shows at the 600 level.

Also, the the very top of the first xaxis tick also renders.  Sometimes I can get an inner vertical scroll to appear and scroll down to see the xaxis ticks, but the first one is higher vertically than the others. I can't see any of the rest of the missing features.

I have tried everything that I can think of:
(1) Adding padding around the container div
(2) setting overflow:auto on that div
(3) removing rendering the labels as canvas
(4) removing autorotate ticks (which appear only on the x axis)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to create an example jsfiddle or plunker.  In it's current form this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @Mark you might be right. Unfortunately, the web site where I have added it is secure, so I can't create a jsfiddle to recreate it. as mentioned, when the chart is stand alone, it works fine, so a jsfiddle likely would too.  I was hoping someone might have a hunch for why that type of thing might happen.

Comment: @Mark, if you're curious, I can invite you to the web site where the chart is not working and you can see for yourself. Can't invite all of Stack, however.

Comment: I have recreated it as a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msalamon/1jd48qkq/2/.  I am surprised to see that some of the ticks are actually cut off here too.  It does not have all of the same issues that I mentioned above, but at least one.  One issue is that the div the chart is added to will appear on the page without sizing and I am trying to dynamically resize the chart to fit a percentage of the page size or some fixed pixel amount. but even if you put in a fixed size, the chart is cut off.

Comment: On the [tickrotor](https://github.com/markrcote/flot-tickrotor) github page, there's this note:  `If you are using this with flot-axislabels, include flot-tickrotor *before*
flot-axislabels, since the former completely redefines the X-axis
labelHeight, and the latter only modifies it.`  If you swap that, [things get a little better](http://jsfiddle.net/1jd48qkq/4/).

Comment: @Mark  Thanks.  That did resolve the issue with the jsfiddle, but made no change to the chart embedded on my web site. :(  If you are interested, I can give you access to the site where the chart is embedded so you can see for yourself.  It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'll take a look, send me the details.  If you don't want to post it publicly my email address is in my profile.

Comment: @Mark I just invited you to the site. Thanks!